# Condition for which a function in $\mathbb C$ is radial

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f:\mathbb R^2\simeq \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is radial if $f(z)=f_0(|z|)$ with $f_0: [0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb C$

The function is radial if and only if  $f(e^{i\theta}z)=f(z)$ $   \forall z\in \mathbb C, \forall \theta \in \mathbb R$?

$\Rightarrow )$ If $f$ is radial $f(z)=f_0(|z|)$.We know that $|z|=|ze^{i \theta}|$ so $f(z)=f_0(|z|)=f_0(|ze^{i \theta}|)=f(ze^{i \theta})$

But for the inverse $\Leftarrow$? if $f(e^{i\theta}z)=f(z)$ then the function is radial?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f(e^{i\theta}z) = f(z)$ and for all $\theta$?

Comment: I correct the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is correct, because you are rotating $z$ by $\theta$ when you multiply and the value remains the same. But the equality has to hold for all $\theta$

Comment: Ok. I want prove the second affermation using the first

Comment: If it is radial, then it depends only on $|z|$, which doesn't change when you multiply